# JEST testing with React

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs

I built a small React App using create-react-app boilerplate.
I'm trying to use JEST(version 20.0.4) to implement some unit tests
but I ran into issues running the tests.
My babel version is 6.26.0.

Here's my test script:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from '../App';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
 const div = document.createElement('div');
 ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
});
```

Here's my Package.json:

```
"jest": {
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
},
"transform": {
  "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/fileTransformer.js"
}}
```

And here's the error message I got when I run the tests:

```
 FAIL  src/test/App.test.jsx
 ● Test suite failed to run

/Users/Bluna/lunathecat-projects/reddit-react-app/src/test/App.test.jsx:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import React from 'react';
                                                                                         ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/ScriptTransformer.js:289:17)
      at <anonymous>
```

This is the first time I've used JEST and I'm not sure what's going on exactly. What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform your files using jest-babel.